# How to calculate an average of numbers when some cells in the range are not a number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to calculate an average number of days to resolve from some data I have.

However, in some cases, because the problem hasn't been resolved yet, Excel thinks the number of days is #NUM!

I'm using the Excel function "DATEDIF", which will give me the difference between 2 dates or give me the #NUM!  A sample of my data is below.

How do I calculate the average when I have #NUM! as one of the values in the column?  How can I get around this issue of non-resolved issues/output from DATEDIF

[image]

Comment: Look into AGGREGATE() it can do average and ignore errors

Answer (score 2):

If all the errors are of type "#NUM!", you could use the
AVERAGEIF function:

```
=AVERAGEIF(range,"<>#NUM!")
```

To ignore errors of all types use the AGGREGATE function:

```
=AGGREGATE(1,6,range)
```

where `1` stands for average and `6` for ignoring errors.

Another possibility uses the IFERROR function to avoid errors:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(range,""))
```

Still another uses FILTER to filter only true numbers:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(range,ISNUMBER(range)))
```

Comment: One note on the `=AVERAGE(IFERROR(range,""))` any version that does not have the Dynamic Arrays, must use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Either use AGGREGATE to average while ignoring errors, or change the DATEDIF function to

```
=IFERROR(DATEDIF(A2, B2, "D"),"")
```

AVERAGE will ignore blank text "". I prefer the latter method simply because AVERAGE is more understandable and your sheet looks nicer.

Actually I prefer not using DATEDIF and just use:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A2), ISNUMBER(B2)), B2-A2, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this:*

[image]

1. Formula in C27: `=AVERAGEIF(C22:C25,">=0")`

*Or an array (CSE) formula:*
`{=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(C22:C25),C22:C25))}`

2. Array (CSE)Formula in C28:
   `{=MEDIAN(IF(ISNUMBER(C22:C25),C22:C25))}`

**N.B.** *Finish an Array (CSE) formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm a sucker for the ol' IF statement....
try:

```
=IF(B22="","",DATEDIF(A22,B22,"MD"))
```

Basically if it hasn't been completed there will no time taken to resolve, which will intern allow the Average & Median to calculate.

Screen Shot of IF statement in action
[image]